# Xcode fails to Build on real iOS device running iOS 13

Tags: ios, xcode, ios13, macos-catalina

I'm currently updated my iPhone XS Max to `iOS 13.0.17A5492t` Beta version.

My mac running on `Mac OS Catalina` and Xcode is on latest stable version not beta >> `Version 10.2.1 (10E1001)`.

When i try to build my apps on my real device i get this compile error:

> This iPhone XS Max is running iOS 13.0 (17A5492t), which may not be supported by this version of Xcode.

### What i've done

1. Download [iOS 13.0 Developer Disk Image](https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport) from repo.
2. Pasted in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport
3. Restart Xcode

but none of above worked.

Comment: Why don’t you update Xcode to 11?

Comment: Because i'm looking for solutions around Xcode 10. my office has a term to use stable version of Xcode.

Comment: You must compile with xcode 11 to run on a real device with ios 13

Comment: But you are the one who installed an _unstable_ version of iOS on your device! You can't have it both ways.

Comment: @matt there was a lot of ways with iOS 12 beta... so i'm looking for those ways i asked clearly...

Answer (score 39, accepted):

your step by step manual you performed actually helped me and now I can work with iOs 13 with xcode 10.2.1. There is only difference, that I downloaded device support files from [this github](https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport/blob/master/DeviceSupport/13.0.zip), so you can try this. And I restarted whole mac to be sure:)

Comment: had to restart!

Answer (score 33):

I downloaded the Developer disk image for iOS 13.0 from here and added support file in Xcode Version 10.3 (10G8).

https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport/blob/master/DeviceSupport/13.0.zip

All other devices support list like 13.3.

https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport/tree/master/DeviceSupport

Follow These steps.

1. Unzip downloaded file.
2. Right click on Xcode and click on `Show Package Content`.
3. Then paste your file on path.

   Applications -> Xcode.app -> Contents -> Developer -> Platforms -> iPhoneOS.platforms -> DeviceSupport

Then at last restart your Xcode.

It works for me.

Comment: As I updated my device iPhone 8 for iOS 13.1, then I got same issue Xcode 10.3, (Not able to debug application in device), I followed same steps as above...  Important thing you download correct version of Device Support Zip file. In my case I downloaded 13.1.zip file. --- Every thing worked thanks :)

Answer (score 7):

iOS 13.1.3 support for Xcode 10.2.1 with macOS Mojave (10.14.4)

- Download iOS 13.1.3 Developer [Disk Image from repo](https://github.com/arshadtp/Xcode-10.2.1---iOS-13.1.3-Support).
- Unzip file 13.1.3 (17A878).
- Past it in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport.
- Restart Xcode.

Comment: Can you explain the significance of the (17A878) after the number version. What does it mean and how do you find it or know what to use?

Comment: It is the iOS build version. Please refer https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS_version_history#iOS_13

Comment: @zztop I don't know honestly that is naming by Xcode, probably some serial number maybe

Answer (score 7):

For all that have a problem with iOS 13.3 this is what I did and it works:
you go to:

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport

then if you don't have 13.2 folder with image download it from github link above, after that just copy 13.2 and rename it to 13.3 (17C54)
and it works

Comment: Can you explain the renaming file.  What does the (17C54) mean or do?