# How to run/install app in iOS 13 device from the Xcode 10.2.1 using device supported file

Tags: ios, xcode10.2, ios13

I have recently updated iPhone to iOS 13 after the update my existing code (which was working fine in iOS 12.3) stopped working.
Getting below error.

[image]

so as a workaround I added device supported file for the iOS 13 in below location

> ⁨Applications⁩ ▸ ⁨Xcode⁩ ▸ ⁨Contents⁩ ▸ ⁨Developer⁩ ▸ ⁨Platforms⁩ ▸ ⁨iPhoneOS.platform⁩ ▸ ⁨DeviceSupport⁩

[image]

even after adding the device support file getting error could not locate the device support files.

Comment: Afaik Xcode 10 doesn't support the iOS13 images. The same question from a few weeks ago remains unanswered: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56521200/95309 - Also, pretty sure you need to name the folder `13.0 (17A5508m)`

Comment: yes, it is working after changing the folder name... Thanks :)

Comment: I copied Xcode 11⁩ ▸ ⁨Contents⁩ ▸ ⁨Developer⁩ ▸ ⁨Platforms⁩ ▸ ⁨iPhoneOS.platform⁩ ▸ ⁨DeviceSupport⁩ ▸ ⁨13.0 to the same path in Xcode 10.3.  I tried building and got the message "Could not locate device support files.  This model Phone 11 is running iOS 13.1.3 (17A878).  I renamed the folder to 13.1.3 (17A878), and was then able to build and run on my iPhone 11 Pro Max.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure you name the folder to match the exact version, i.e. `13.0 (17A5508m)`

Answer (score 2):

I downloaded the Developer disk image for iOS 13.0 from here and added support file in Xcode Version 10.3 (10G8).

https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport/blob/master/DeviceSupport/13.0.zip

All other devices support list.

https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport/tree/master/DeviceSupport

Follow These steps.

Unzip downloaded file.
Right click on Xcode and click on Show Package Content.
Then paste your file on path.

Applications -> Xcode.app -> Contents -> Developer -> Platforms -> iPhoneOS.platforms -> DeviceSupport

Then at last restart your Xcode.

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

PS: Don't forget to restart Xcode after drag&drop device support folder.

Answer (score -1):

Download `xcode11 Beta` and take `Disk Image for iOS 13` from `xcode 11 Beta` device support.
It will work for you.

Comment: "take Disk Image for iOS 13 from xcode 11 Beta device support. It will work for you." A good answer should be more specific and declarative