# How to download iOS-DeviceSupport files without download new version of Xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I want to run my application by Xcode 10.1.2 in iPhone 13.1.3 but I am getting an error

This iPhone 6s is running iOS 13.1.3 (17A878), which may not be supported by this version of Xcode.

I found this article 
https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport
but I am getting this error sudo: ./deploy.py: command not found.

I don't want to upgrade my Xcode at this time. Can any one suggest me an alternate way.

Comment: Did u check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56521200/xcode-fails-to-build-on-real-ios-device-running-ios-13

Comment: Thank you yes this answer works for me. 
https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport

Comment: https://github.com/xushuduo/Xcode-iOS-Developer-Disk-Image/releases this link help you'